# Presenting summary statistics

Tags: descriptive-statistics, presentation

For a section reporting descriptive statistics should I use the non-transformed variables $x$ or the transformed variables used in the regression analysis (e.g. differenced logs of a variable, $\Delta \text{log}x$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually say do both. I think it's more important to describe the non-transformed data because, well, that's the data you have. However, describing the transformed data tells about what you ended up analyzing and could also give the reader insight into why you had to transform the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer here and very much depends on your research question and methodology. In general, when reporting you should always ask yourself: What do I want to tell the reader?

In case of transforming variables you should be **very** careful when reporting. Make sure you can justify your transformation and thus can anser the following questions:

- Does the transformed variable still make sense?
- What is your reasoning to transform the variable?
- Did the regression differ between using non-transformed and transformed variables?

Make sure to report on the answers of these questions.

Comment: @Fraujke Thanks for your answer. Say the transformations makes sense and has been performed in order to get stationary variables. The regression cannot be performed on non-transformed variables. What would then be your answer?

Comment: Then you can (by the just mentioned arguments) justify the transformation. Thus you can use the transformed variables in further analysis (e.g. a regression) and report them accordingly.

Comment: Concerning the third bullet, I am curious about why one would even bother to perform a regression on untransformed (raw) values when the appropriate statistical procedure was to use the transformed values. I'm also a little puzzled about how one would put the first bullet into operation: in what way, for instance, would a square root of a value not "make sense" but a logarithm would? If you maintain both of these make sense, then what about (say) the $-0.63$ power? What is the criterion for "making sense" and why should it take primacy over evaluating the quality of the overall analysis?

Comment: @whuber What would your answer to the question posted by OP (me) be?

Comment: @whuber There are a LOT of instances where transformations physically make sense, for sound intensity data: taking a square root does not make sense while a logarithmic transformation does since sound intensity generally scales on a logarithmic scale. So with making sense I mean: does the transformation physically make sense?

Comment: @Sunv Usually in a magazine there's no room to report on both non-transformed and transformed data. In this case: go for the transformation (although I was trying to let you come up with this yourself!), in your SI you might want to report on outcomes of your non-transformed data analysis then, or a more elaborate rationale for using the transformation.

Comment: @Fraukje What does SI mean? Reporting the transformations won't be of any meaning to the reader. Say for instance that the variables are related to financial information of the companies in the data sample. Descriptive statistics on e.g. market capitalization would be possible to interpret whereas a log-transformed presentation of market capitalization would be difficult to interpret. I also get your point about space limits in journal articles. However, I have enough space, so reporting descriptive statistics for both transformed and non-transformed data seems like a good idea.

Comment: Although "physically making sense" is an important guide in scientific discovery of basic physical laws, this is a small subset of statistical problems. When the data are, say, results of opinion polls or socio-economic statistics or even intensities of earthquakes, such considerations of "making sense" are unnecessarily limiting and may even hinder development of effective analyses of the data. Your second bullet really is the pertinent one: provide adequate justification for the transformation.

Comment: Yeah that's true!